# Connecting to remote activemq instance running on docker container

Tags: java, activemq-classic, docker

I have 2 docker containers, one running a spring app (in tomcat) and one running an active mq instance. When I try to connect to it from my spring app, I get the following error. Only activeMQ is running on the one container and the port is properly exposed. I verified the IP address of the docker container (shown below) and that is correct.

I'm not sure what could be causing this error at this point. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

> > ERROR [activemq.broker.BrokerService] Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([mybroker, ID:489af431756c-60313-1409695404227-0:1], java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://172.17.0.2:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address)

Comment: Please, give us two distinct names to the two machines in the context of this issue (for example `app` and `mq`). Which machine this error comes from?

Comment: one is named `tomcat` and one is named `activemq`

Comment: And where does this message come from?

Comment: The logs of the spring app when it tries to connect to the active mq broker

Comment: Not sure about this message, but seems a binding error, not a connection error, like if the spring app tried to start an ActiveMQ broker on the IP of the `activemq` instance, and of course fails. Can you show the Spring configuration?

Comment: That's exactly what happened. I was just re-reading the spring config and it does look like that is what's happening. Can you post this as an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: Posted my answer. Attached the sample from the ActiveMQ documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configured Spring to start a broker service on 172.17.0.2, which is the IP of the remote machine. Instead, you should configure Spring to connect to an existing broker on that machine. From the [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html) and using the Spring facility JMSTemplate:

```xml
<!-- a pooling based JMS provider -->
<bean id="jmsFactory"
      class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
      destroy-method="stop">
  <property name="connectionFactory">
    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
      <property name="brokerURL">
        <value>tcp://activemq-host.local:61616</value>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>

<!-- Spring JMS Template -->
<bean id="myJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
  <property name="connectionFactory">
    <ref local="jmsFactory"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```